# Optimizing Models

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm still very new to machine learning and was trying a few competitions on Kaggle, namely, the housing price one. I did everything according the tutorial and it worked out fine. However, I read elsewhere that if a training score is scoring much better than the testing score, that is a sign of overfitting. So I adjusted max_depth of the random forest to 3 in hopes to correct for it, and my training score and testing score got closer as I hoped. However, when I submitted my new csv, I got a worse score. What was wrong with my logic, am I missing something? I did notice that both the training and the test score, while it was closer, it became worse than before, is it a probable reason that I was underfitting now?

Thanks!

FYI - the numbers (Mean Absolute Error):
initial:

```
Test Score: 21,857
Train Score: 8,584
```

after max_depth of 3:

```
Test Score: 28,745
Train Score: 28,072
```

Comment: How large was the drop on the leaderboard? If it wasn't large, it could be random noise in the testing data. Also, did you try to cross-validate your model? What were the results? Share some numbers if possible.

Comment: Drop was pretty large. Didn't cross validate because I haven't learned that yet, I'm going to post the numbers onto the original post.

Comment: The drop is obvious since your test error has increased. You must decrease both the errors with ratio close to one.